# Clear default text

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I am looking to clear the "$" symbol that I am setting using jquery in a sharepoint field. Because it is a currency data type, the "$" cannot be in it when the form is saved if it does not have a number after it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    ('[title="Disbursement Approval"]').val("$");
    });
```

when I hit the save button, it should clear the "Disbursment Approval" field if the only thing in the field is the "$" symbol.

Ex: $123.00 (it should leave it alone on save)
Ex: $ (it should remove the "$" and leave it blank)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I recommend a prefix of some kind before the actual form, rather than populating the input itself?

Answer (score 0):

To clear input:

```
$('#saveBtn').on("click", function() {
  var $approval = $('[title="Disbursement Approval"]'),
      approvalVal = $approval.val();

  if (approvalVal == "$") $approval.val("");

  // Rest code...
});
```

Or, if you want to get value right away:

```
$('#saveBtn').on("click", function() {
  var $approval= $('[title="Disbursement Approval"]'),
      approvalValue = ($approval.val() == "$") ? "" : ($approval.val());

  // Rest code...
});
```